# Unknown origin of green dots

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm new to openlayers, so excuse me for a rookie question. Basically, I make a request to an API, get a route ans show it on the map, using the yelow line and green dots. The dots are not svg/pdf or whatnot, they seem to be a part of openlayers, so could someone who is knowledgeable about openlayers please tell me from what part of the openlayers module these dots are coming from? 
[image]

Comment: Can you share the code? Can you provide some details of the API?

Comment: Most likely they come from a style on your vector layer but how could we possibly know from what you've provided?

Comment: Yea,they come from there, thanks.

Comment: add your initial code here.. or create jsfiddle...